# scikit-learn, add features to a vectorized set of documents

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I am starting with scikit-learn and I am trying to transform a set of documents into a format on which I could apply clustering and classification. I have seen the details about the vectorization methods, and the tfidf transformations to load the files and index their vocabularies.

However, I have extra metadata for each documents, such as the authors, the division that was responsible, list of topics, etc.

How can I add features to each document vector generated by the vectorizing function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `DictVectorizer` for the extra categorical data and then use [scipy.sparse.hstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.hstack.html) to combine them.

Comment: excellent, I will try, but hstack seems to be what I need. Thanks!