# How can I add features other than BOW to scikit-learn classification models

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-classification

I'm trying to build a text-classification model. My goal is to classify each paragraph in 10000 documents into whether it has information on 'Labor Strike Event' or not.

First, I followed the basic preprocessing steps and transformed the paragraphs into a term-document matrix (CountVectorizer). Then feed this matrix to the models such as logistic regression and svm provided by scikit-learn.

However, I found the information on the topic of documents, which is given by pre-trained LDA model would be helpful for paragraph level text-classification.

Hence I want to also feed information on topics along with BOW information for each text.

Following the answer to the [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257674/scikit-learn-add-features-to-a-vectorized-set-of-documents) question, I think that simply adding topic number at the last column of term-document matrix.

For example, let 'text_train' be my training corpus (say 40000 paragraphs) and 'topic' be the list of topic number given to each paragraph by LDA model.

```py
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,3))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(text_train)  
X.toarray() #shape (40000, 643898)
topic = coo_matrix([topic]).T #shape (40000, 1)
hstack([X.toarray(), topic]).toarray() #shape (40000, 643899)
```

This returns the desired matrix whose last column has information on topics.

However, since the topic numbers do not have cardinal (or ordinal) order like elements of term-document matrix does, I am worried that some linear machine learning model might not be proper for this work.

Is is true? Then is there any other solutions that I can adopt?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right; `Topic` column is not a cardinal/ordinal feature.

You could use [oneHotEncoding()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) of the `topic` feature and then append it with `countVectorizer` output.

Another option (which I think as better approach), you could feed the probability of each topic (which you can get by using `lda.transform()` function) as the additional feature.